# Calculating age in days - Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, dynamic, textbox

Okay, so I have three text boxes. My goal is to have a fourth text box that is generated when the user clicks the button. The fourth text box should be populated with the input from the other three boxes. I've managed to do this with the code here:

```
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
      <script>
         function addTextBox() {
         var element = document.createElement("input");

         element.setAttribute("type", "text");
         element.setAttribute("id", "Text4");
         document.body.appendChild(element);

         fill();
         }

         function fill() {
         input = document.getElementById("Text1").value + " " + document.getElementById("Text2").value + " is " + document.getElementById("Text3").value;;;
         document.getElementById('Text4').value = input;
         }

      </script>
      <form>
         <input type="text" id="Text1" value="Firstname">
         <input type="text" id="Text2" value="Lastname">
         <input type="text" id="Text3" value="Age">
         <input type="button" onclick="addTextBox()">
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

But there's one last thing I need to do. When the user inputs their age in the third textbox, I need to have in converted to their age in days before it appears in the fourth box.

Can anybody help me do this?

Comment: How could you manage to convert an age which is in years to days? It would be very very gross: you could be 355 days wrong... you cannot obtain the days only from the years.

Comment: use  date of birth instead of  age in years to get age in days

Comment: This is for an assignment and it says that the user enters their age and their age in days should be returned. Is there really no way to do this? Perhaps I misunderstood.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the number of days between two dates in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-javascript)

Comment: No. No dates are involved. Just the number of years and the number of days.

Answer (score 2):

Hey you can use below function to calcuate no of days by passing age

```
 function totalDays(age)
    {
    var now = new Date();
    var start = new Date();
    start.setFullYear((now.getFullYear()-age))
    var diff = now - start;
    var oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    var day = Math.floor(diff / oneDay);
    return day ;
    }
```